# Swift exc_bad_access when applying a function

Tags: ios, json, swift, functional-programming

A'right guys, I'm stumped.

So I'm working on a functional json implementation along the lines of [this article](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/efficient-json-in-swift-with-functional-concepts-and-generics).  Things are going fairly well, but I have this one issue that persists in both current and beta versions of Xcode and Swift.

My decode logic takes an argument from the JSON dictionary on the left, and uses a decode function provided on the right, composing them with the 'bind' operator:

```
return AdUnitDictionary.create <^>
    d["adRepeats"]          >>> _JSONInt        <*>
    d["adStartsAfter"]      >>> _JSONInt        <*>
    d["advertisingOn"]      >>> _JSONInt        <*>
    d["numberOfCards"]      >>> _JSONInt        <*>
    d["adUnitIdNonRetina"]  >>> _JSONString     <*>
    d["adUnitIdRetina"]     >>> _JSONString
```

Bind is defined like this:

```
func >>><A, B>(a: Result<A>, f: A -> Result<B>) -> Result<B> {
    switch a {
    case let .Value(x):     return f(x.value)
    case let .Error(error): return .Error(error)
    }
}
```

So, originally, this method tries to cast the string and returns a safe, empty string in the event of failure.  I thought that I was getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS from my if-let block:

```
func _JSONString(object: JSON) -> String {
    if let object = object as? String { return object } // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    return ""
}
```

Because that 'if-let' line is where the debugger shows the exception to be thrown.  However!  Eliminating that block, and using a function that ignores its arguments ENTIRELY, causes the exception to be thrown on the return!!

```
func _JSONString(object: JSON) -> String {
    return "" // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
}
```

The only sense I can make of this is that the function being applied is nil, since the argument itself is checked to exist in the implementation of bind.  This doesn't make sense, however, because the debugger makes it right into my target function before throwing its exception.

Another mystery is why the numeric decodes succeed without any issue, even though they're just carbon-copies of the string decoder with a different type specialization.

Any ideas?

Comment: the last is very interesting ... i am not able to believe that

Comment: Do you have an example input data that reliably reproduces this? It seems likely that the actual problem is outside of the code you're presented. Alternately I would suspect that the actual crash is happening on some other queue. I would simplify this problem to a smaller program that demonstrates it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm also getting a bad access when returning to a generic function.

Answer (score 0):

check you pattern!

```
let object: Int? = nil
if let object = object as? String {
    print("a")
} else {
    print("nil")
}
// prints nil
```

or

```
let object: Int = 1
if let object = object as? String {
    print("a")
} else {
    print("nil")
}
// prints nil
```